# AlarmManager и сон

Tags: android, android-alarm-manager

Похожий вопрос уже был здесь на ресурсе, но очень давно и решался он по другому так как был для другого API. Есть у меня AlarmManager в двух реализациях: `setRepeating()` и `setExactl()`. Первый срабатывает за 2 часа до времени Х второй это время Х. Первый запускает сервис и тот варится в системе до момента времени Х с бессмертным уведомлением. Я устанавливаю первый, он срабатывает и после этого я перевожу устройство в сон кнопкой отключения, но второй срабатывает с задержкой от одной секунды до нескольких минут. Добавил блокировку сна, но и это мне не помогло.

Блокировка сна взята из [DescClock](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/) (у всех эти часы есть):

```
/**
* Utility class to hold wake lock in app.
*/
public class AlarmAlertWakeLock {

private static final String TAG = "AlarmAlertWakeLock";

private static PowerManager.WakeLock sCpuWakeLock;

public static PowerManager.WakeLock createPartialWakeLock(Context context) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    return pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
}

public static void acquireCpuWakeLock(Context context) {
    if (sCpuWakeLock != null) {
        return;
    }

    sCpuWakeLock = createPartialWakeLock(context);
    sCpuWakeLock.acquire();
}

public static void acquireScreenCpuWakeLock(Context context) {
    if (sCpuWakeLock != null) {
        return;
    }
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    sCpuWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK
            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, TAG);
    sCpuWakeLock.acquire();
}

public static void releaseCpuLock() {
    if (sCpuWakeLock != null) {
        sCpuWakeLock.release();
        sCpuWakeLock = null;
    }
}
}
```

Или я не правильно использую данный класс (хотя в принципе должно быть достаточно только флага: `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` - исходя из этой [статьи](https://software.intel.com/ru-ru/android/articles/wakelocks-for-android)).

Может кто знает как "правильно" блокировать сон устройство или нашел инное решение.

Кстати интересный момент, когда устройство подключено к пк задержек больше нескольких секунд замечено не было.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте разобраться как работает JobService. Начиная с андроид 8, таймеры останавливаются в режиме сна. JobService работает четко, блокировать режим сна не придется.

Comment: Вот у меня сейчас проблема, на некоторых устройствах JobService с тайминогм не срабатывает.