# Нет документации

Tags: android

Воюю с [вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/983881/238266). Наткнулся на класс(или как будет правильнее выразится): `WakeLocks` из артефактов `AndroidX` (этот класс лежит по адресу: `androidx.work.impl.util`). Но документации не нашел, даже [здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/package-summary). Вопросы:

1. Где пошуршить доку? В самом классе как-то маловато инфы.
2. Я так понимаю она сейчас тестируется? Но в классе пометок на эту тему нигде не нашел. И соответственно вопрос: стоит ли заморачиваться с ней или нет...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не там искали, это компонент системы, не AndroidX.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock

Скорее этот класс вас интересует.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager

**Дополнено**
Классы в пакетах `impl`, `internal` и т.п. обычно подразумевают использование для внутренних потребностей компонента. Поэтому и нет документации.
И не стоит его напрямую использовать, разработчики в любой момент могут его изменить или убрать совсем.

А в исходники заглянуть стоит.
https://zgrepcode.com/android/9.0.0/androidx/work/impl/utils/wakelocks.java

По сути это обертка для создания все тех же системных `PowerManager.WakeLock`.

Comment: Там, не зря я написал WackLocks (с "S") этот класс лежит по адресу: androidx.work.impl.util. если у вас есть возможность подключить библиотеку: androidx.work вы сами сможете в этом убедиться.

Comment: Я заглянул в вопрос, с которым воюете :) Там был только PowerManager.WakeLock. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: по поводу impl и internal не знал, спасибо. Я тоже смотрел, немного отличается реализация из-за этого и заинтересовался. Считаю вопрос закрытым.