# Уведомление-напоминание в выбранное пользователем время

Tags: java, android, уведомления, android-notification, android-alarm-manager

Очень нужна ваша помощь.

Пишу приложение вроде планировщика событий или списка дел. Классика жанра: штука, которую хочу реализовать, есть в любом подобном приложении. Нужно, чтобы за час (за два, это не принципиально, указать время можно в любой момент, насколько я понимаю), пользователю приходило уведомление типа "На 18:00 у Вас есть планы..".

Много искала, читала про AlarmManager и подобное, не могу применить к своему проекту, ничего не работает, когда приложение закрыто.
Что делать?

Как организовать отправку пользователю **notifications в заданный день и время, независимо от того, запущено ли приложение** ?

Comment: то есть вы хотите, чтобы ваше приложение что то сделало в момент, когда оно не запущено?

Comment: Вы в правильном направлении копали, на данный момент ничего больше не придумали, только AlarmManger, но там не всё так просто, начните с его реализации, реализуйте что бы он работал с включенным экраном, тут есть ссылки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/983881/238266, , дальше углубляйтесь в изучении этой темы нужно будет почитать про Doze: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby. Там есть рекомендации по оптимизации. Хорошо бы начать с API19, там будет проще...

Comment: @tym32167 но ведь такое возможно и используется постоянно... В играх, в напоминалках каких-то... Или я  что-то неправильно понимаю?

Comment: Везде AlarmMananger используют с BroadcastReceiver, это не панацея,я для своих целей использовал сервис, который включается за два часа до момента X, если вы пользовались будильником, то видели что у вас в шторке есть уведомление о событии таком то, это для того чтобы система не убила его до нужного момента.

Comment: @Valeriy, спасибо, я  посмотрю... Как я успела уже понять, легких путей разработчики Android не ищут)

Comment: Как по мне, Андроид это лучшее с чем из мобильной разработки вы могли связаться, сейчас у вас есть возможность найти решение на любую свою задачу, если нет, то вы можете её реализовать, более или менее сложно, в иных же платформах, вы или не сможете это сделать или нужно будет душу дьяволу продать... Ну это сугубо моё мнение! P.S. работа с такими вещами очень сложный момент, вы ведь не хотите чтобы ваш смартфон разряжался за очень короткий промежуток времени? Вот по этому всё так сложно...

Comment: Хорошо, что вы попробовали прикрутить Alarm Manager и может даже прочитали, что-то про другие сервисы. Я советую изучить WorkManager, чтобы сложная задача превратилась в банальщину, а также отпала необходимость изобретать костыли под разные апи. Главное его преимущество это гарантия, что задача выполнится с API 14+. И не нужно будет парится об managers, services, receivers, job schedulers, doze mode и прочей нечисти. https://medium.com/@ifr0z/workmanager-notification-date-and-time-pickers-aad1d938b0a3 Поможет понять для чего, зачем, почему, с какими проблемами столкнешься, и как их преодолеть.

Comment: @iFr0z я с вами согласен, но есть одна небольшая проблема, вы бы хотели опоздать на важную встречу или даже на день рождение к своему ребёнку ибо ваш график на столько плотный что вам приходится полагаться на свой список задач, который вас должен предупредить? Так вот, используя WorkManager не гарантирует выполнение задачи в чётко указанный момент, по этой самой причине мне и пришлось отказаться от его использования. P.S. Если вы пишете хорошую статью, всё бы ру сообщество было вам благодарно, если бы вы делали и ру версию... Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @Valeriy там разница буквально в секундах) да и как по мне лучше уж пусть задача выполнится с опозданием, чем вообще не выполнится у кого-нить, но это лирика уже :)